# SpriteKitの右下に表示される「nodes・・・」はどのように消せますか？

Tags: swift, ios, iphone, spritekit, game-development

SwiftのSpriteKitでGameを作成しようと思っています。

SpriteKitで実行すると右下に画像のような「nodes・・・」の文字が表示されます。
この文字はどのように消せますか？

Game開発が初めての為、初歩的な質問で申し訳御座いませんが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。

[image: 対象の画像]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpriteKit使用のGameテンプレートで作ったプロジェクトか、何かのサンプルコードを引っ張ってきたものでしょうか?

GameViewController.swiftの中に以下のようなコードはないでしょうか?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true //<-
        view.showsNodeCount = true //<-
    }
}
```

`//<-`のところを`false`にしてみて下さい。

たまには`SKView`のような関連クラスのリファレンスを自分で探求してみるのも良い学習になります。

[`SKView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview)

[`var showsFPS: Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1519590-showsfps)

[`var showsNodeCount: Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520156-showsnodecount)

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。

確かに、ご指摘頂いた通りサンプルをベースに開発していました！
対象箇所をfalseとする事で改善しました！
関連リファレンスも読むように致します！！